# My custom stop-words list using tf-idf

Tags: nlp, tfidf

I want to make my own stop words list, I computed tf-idf scores for my terms.

Can I consider those words highlighted with red to be stop word? and what should my threshold be for stop words that depend on tf-idf? Should I consider the high values of tf-idf as the most important words that I need to keep?

[image]

@Erwan answered this question, check their answer to the question they linked too it is very informative

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- There's no standard definition of stop-word, but in general stop words are very frequent words which don't contribute to the meaning of the text, like determiners, pronouns, etc. Importantly stop-word is a property which applies to unique words in the vocabulary. For example if the word $w$ is considered as a stop-word then this applies to all the occurrences of $w$ in the text, not only to some of them.
- On the contrary TFIDF applies to the words in the sentences/documents, so the same word $w$ may have a different TFIDF value in different sentences/documents:

  - IDF is a property at the vocabulary level, i.e. all the occurrences of $w$ have the same IDF.
  - TF is specific to the sentence/document. If $w$ appears 3 times more often in document A than in document B, then it has 3 times higher TFIDF value in A than in B.

This is why it doesn't really make sense to consider the TFIDF value to select stop-words: the former is specific to a sentence/document but not the second. You could use the IDF part only, but there's no difference with just using the document frequency, and practically it would give the same results as using the overall frequency.

Comment: @FjkgB yes, if you want to optimize the system you can try different thresholds and pick the best one based on the performance. Note that in theory you should do this on a validation set, it's like hyper-parameter tuning (in practice it's not so important in this case). But it's also common to just decide an arbitrary threshold, for example defining every word which appears more than 100 times as stop word. Also it's not related but if you're going to do some classification task it's also useful to remove the *least frequent* words (it's often more useful than the most frequent words).

Comment: I deleted my first comment by mistake, but thank you so much for the extra information too about removing the least frequent terms being more useful.

Comment: @FjkgB in case you want more detail about why it's useful to get rid of rare words you can have a look at this [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/88805/64377).

Comment: Your answer to that another question is a treasure

Comment: @FjkgB Happy to help :)

Comment: What about the average TF-IDF values of words in different sentences. It makes sense since the stop-words shouldn't contribute to the semantics of the documents (in this case, sentences).

Comment: @MehdiAbbassi You mean taking the average TFIDF across sentences for every unique word, right? yes this would work, but it's a technically complex way to do something simple: if one just counts the frequency of every unique word in the corpus, in general the highest frequency words are stop words and other words are content words.

Comment: @Erwan Then since you consider stop words as the complement of content words, they are the same as function words, right?

Comment: More or less, but there is no strict definition of 'stop words', it's anything predefined one wants to remove. 'Function words' or 'grammatical word' is more specific in theory, but in practice the three are often used for the same meaning so yes, actually they are considered the same.