# NLP LSTM input basic doubt

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, lstm, rnn

I have a basic doubt with regards to conversion of text to numbers and feeding it to LSTM. I am aware of the different methods such as OneHot, CountVectorizer, TfIDF, Word2vec etc. My doubt is, If we use a Count Vectoriser or Tfidf, Then in LSTM, we have to pass through the entire vocabulary of words for each sentence since that's how TFIDF and count vectoriser encodes the sentences. Am I right?

My second doubt is, If we use TFIDF or COuntVectorizer, Each word will have different value based on its occurrence and frequency. This is in contrast to Word2Vec where a embedding is learned and used. If each time the LSTM model sees different values for a particular word, How can it learn? Like in a sentence if the word "Hi" appears 6 times, Its encoded with the number 6 in its appropriate index, And in another sentence if it appears 4 times, we encode with the value 4. How does this work? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/88805/64377) about traditional representation of text.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of the answer posted there, Could you kindly resolve the specific doubt I am facing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the traditional bag of words representation and the word embedding representation is that:

- bag of words: every *index* of a vector represents a specific word. Since there must be an index for every possible word, the dimension of every vector must indeed be the full vocabulary size.
- embedding: words and sentences are represented in an (usually pre-trained) embedding space. The dimension of this space is predefined and arbitrary, and there's no way to know directly what every index represents. Indirectly, it can be proved that indexes can represent quite precise semantic concepts.

Anyway, in both cases the features *values* (which can vary) don't carry the meaning, it's always the fixed *indexes* which represent a particular semantic concept.

In your example, say the word "Hi" has index 1234: the fact that this specific index contains 6 or 4 allows the model to recognize a similarity between these 2 sentences. Note that in an embedding representation it's also  the indexes which carry the concept. For example maybe "Hi" would have a important value for the dimension related to "salutations" and this would allow the model to find a similarity with worlds like "hello", "dear X", etc.

Comment: But if I am doing a machine Translation, And I have a list of sentences to translate, How does it make sense to use Tf-idf since each sentence will be encoded to full vocabulary size.

Comment: And also, If suppose I have a sentence "It is Raining" and "Theres a storm here", and I have to predict 0/1. If I use word embeddings, I need to only pass in the given words embeddings and obtain the output label. If I use Tf-idf, I have to pass the entire vocabulary for each sentence to my LSTM to obtain thee output. And moreover, The order of words is not preserved in TFIDF, So, How will it work?

Comment: Again, If I have a word embedding, Each word will have some specific dimension vector. So If I have "It is Raining" "It is snowing" The word "It" appears twice but will get the same word embedding in both the sentences. But in tiff, the word "it" will have different value for each sentence. How will the model know ?

Comment: @mewbie machine translation (MT) is a whole different problem, because it's not mainly about representing the text, it's about finding the alignment from one language to another. I'm not up to date with recent MT models. But do you mean that you want to *train* a MT model, or just apply a model to find the translation? In any case you would probably have to ask a different question. Also imho it's easier to understand the basics of text representation (for example in classification) first, before something advanced like MT.

Comment: point 2: that's not totally exact that you only pass the word embeddings, because you still need a way to represent the sentence as a whole in the embedding space. The deep network may do this job for you, but at some level there's a representation of the full sentence somewhere, and since the values are real numbers this representation is actually more complex and more acccurate than a sparse array. The number of dimensions is only one part of the complexity. And yes, by definition the order  of the words is lost in "bag of words" (hence the term).

Comment: point 3 is what I tried to explain. Take a very simple model, for example decision tree. The tree is made of rules such as `feature[i] >= 2`. If `feature[i]` represents the word "it", two instances which have different values for `feature[i]`, say 3 and 15, will both satisfy this rule. It's crucial to understand this point about the index, because it's the basis even in more complex models. You could try to manually simulate a very basic input text with a very basic type of model to understand this point.

Comment: Yes Sir, I actually got that concept of index. But this question is specifically with respect to Sequence models and not the traditional ones. I am aware that in traditional models, The feature column order is to be preserved and that's how the model learns and knows. But in the case of RNN and sequence models, We basically give it some sentence and expect some output. In this case, If we are giving our RNN a sentence such as "It is raining it", Here we willl pass it word by word. Here is where I got confused. We can use One hot encoding or Word2vec

Comment: But if we use tfidf, The word "it" will be passed with some value, In another sentence if "it" appears 4 times, it will have a different value. In the case of RNN and sequence models, We don't have feature columns like traditional models. Sequence length is variable and it can have any combination of words. So for our model to know this word is this, We need some fixed representation like One hot or word2vec. am I right sir? Thank you for taking the time to answer. it means a lot! Kindly clarify this!

Comment: I'm not the best person to explain LSTM, I'm not very knowledgeable about DNN. But I think that comparing the input vector for bag-of-words to the input word vectors is not the right level of comparison. I think it's common to interpret LSTM (or other types of DNNs) as a full ML process which includes complex feature engineering, so the input given to the network is equivalent to the raw words, whereas the bag-of-words input is the final processed representation (even though it's very basic).

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanation is not clear enough, but you still have a misunderstanding: the link for the word "it" is the index of the word (same for every instance), not the value of a particular instance. The value is only used to measure the "strength" of this particular word. But it's actually the same principle in the LSTM, only this happens *inside* the network with a latent (hidden) representation.

Comment: I was hoping somebody else more expert on LSTM would answer, but if this doesn't happen you could try to ask a new question (preferably more specific).